# Recursively add file contents to file in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In shell I am hoping to do the following:

For every file found in the /etc/test/ folder, take the contents and add it to the following:

```
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The idea is to have files in this folder, each with a key, and for every file found the key is added to the authorized_keys.

I'm new to shell but this is how far I got:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/etc/test/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Adding $f key"
  cat $f >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
done
```

However when I run this it doesnt seem to work. Can anyone give me any reason why it mayn ot be working?

Comment: _Automagically_ appending data to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` sounds scary!

Comment: Your script does the same as cat $FILES >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: @pfnuesel Except it doesn't. Due to the unquoted assignment to `FILES` this is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `find` for *recursive* file searching and pipe its output as command line arguments to `cat` using `xargs`

```
find /etc/test/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote the assignment to your `FILES` variable. The way it is written, if there are no files in `/etc/test`, `FILES` gets assigned the literal string `/etc/test/*`. If there is a single file, then your script will work correctly. If there is more than one, that line will expand to `FILES=/etc/test/file1 /etc/test/file2 ...`, which temporarily assigns `/etc/test/file1` to `FILES` and then tries to run `/etc/test/file2` with the rest of the files as arguments, which is likely to fail.